# Extracting a numerical value from a paragraph based on preceding words

Tags: regex, presto

I'm working with some big text fields in columns. After some cleanup I have something like below:

```
truth_val: ["5"]
xerb Scale: ["2"]
perb Scale: ["1"]
```

I want to extract the number 2. I'm trying to match the string "xerb Scale" and then extract 2. I tried capturing the group including 2 as `(?:xerb Scale:\s\[\")\d{1}` and tried to exclude the matched group through a negative look ahead but had no luck.

This is going to be in a SQL query and I'm trying to extract the numerical value through a `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` function. This query is part of a pipeline that loads this information into the database.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract_all or https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Yes, I'm using the same regex functions in presto. I'm looking for the right pattern to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match what you do not need to obtain in order to set the context for your match, and you need to match *and capture* what you need to extract:

```
xerb Scale:\s*\["(\d+)"]
                 ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP90Rb/1). In Presto, use [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract) to get the first match:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(col, 'xerb Scale:\s*\["(\d+)"]', 1); -- 2
                                                      ^^^
```

Note the `1` argument:

> **`regexp_extract(string, pattern, group) → varchar`**
> Finds the first occurrence of the regular expression `pattern` in `string` and returns the [capturing group number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#gnumber) `group`